# networksetup equivalent for Linux, to set network autoproxy url

Tags: linux, proxy

I read some where to set autoproxy url:

```
PROXY_FILE_PATH="$DIR/proxy.pac"
sudo networksetup -setautoproxystate Wi-Fi off
sudo networksetup -setautoproxyurl Wi-Fi file://$PROXY_FILE_PATH
sudo networksetup -getautoproxyurl Wi-Fi
```

and searched for `networksetup` and found that it seems to be for Mac only.

Is there any such equivalent thing for Linux to set autoproxyurl?

**Note:**

The question is more on setting auto proxy url, rather than proxy itself.
I.e., it is about using the [Proxy Auto-Configuration (PAC) file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_(PAC)_file) system wide, and preferably the setup is done on command line.

Comment: It depends on which distribution - for example, here's for Debian (and therefore Ubuntu and Mint and ... anything based on Debian).  https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-set-system-wide-proxy-on-ubuntu-debian/

Comment: Yes @ivanivan, I use Debian (and therefore Ubuntu and Mint etc). However the question is on setting autoproxyurl. I'll update OP to explain what it is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a bit late, but I came here looking for the same answer and eventually found it. You can use `gsettings` to turn proxy to 'auto' and specify a PAC URL:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy autoconfig-url "https://your-pac-url"
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'auto'
```

Note: Set it to 'none' instead of 'auto' to disable it.

You can see the current settings using `get` instead of `set`:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy autoconfig-url
gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy mode
```

And you can see what keys are available to set for the proxy settings using:

```
gsettings list-keys org.gnome.system.proxy
```

Comment: Thanks, and welcome! +25!